ebike speed sensor issue
My Pure Flux One (single gear, ebike) pedal assist works/kicks in for v short time setting off but 'speed sensor' alert shows & motor/pedal assist stops within 10-30 secs. turning display off/on will work again in same way (& odd occasion it will 'reset' without turning display off but will cut out again within seconds). I've looked carefully for sensor/magnet on stays/brake rotor assembly etc but can't find anything. If I'm correct, I'm aware that some motors have speed sensors/magnets contained in the 'sealed unit'. For those who don't know the Pure Flux One, is a single gear - not sure if that might effect where/how speed sensor might work? Any thoughts would be v welcome to enable me to fix a cheap/used ebike (which is all I can stretch to right now unfortunately). Thank you in advance.

I had the same symptoms on my E bike after about 8000 km. The sensor just stopped working without obvious reason. Check the magnet for the last time, and if doesn't look misaligned with the sensor - nothing to do, replace the sensor.

Thank you for reply, much appreciated & sounds sensible. However, my question is where is that magnet/sensor on a Pure Flux One - it’s not obvious & I’m trying to find out if it’s actually in the motor hub itself (rather than an external sensor & spoke/brake rotor mounted magnet).
